# Mysql update table columns from other table

Tags: mysql

hi guys so i want to update one table from other table but once i run this query it does nothing, any tips? im using email on the condition because that value is unique. thanks!.

```
      $query= "UPDATE avisosPrivacidad a, temporal b SET
      a.s1Correo                 = b.email,
      a.s1Giro                   = b.giro,


      a.s1DatosPersonales        = b.datosPersona,
      a.s1MotivoYUso             = b.usoInformacion,
      a.s4FinesDeTransferencia   = b.finesDeTransaccion,
      a.s7NombreSitioWeb         = b.nombreWeb,
      a.s8Actualizacion          = b.actualizacion


      WHERE a.s1Correo = b.email;";
```

Comment: You'll need to `JOIN` the tables together.

Comment: You are using comma operator for the inner join. This is format is valid per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)   Does your avisosPrivacidad and temporal tables have matching email addresses?  I ask because the "a.s1Correo = b.email" sets them to the same value.

Comment: @WorkSmarter yes they have the same email because the "temporal" gets filled with data from "avisosPrivacidad" then theres a system that can make changes to "temporal" once the changes are done it should return the values to the "avisosPrivacidad" that table is like the principal one

Comment: UPDATE avisosPrivacidad a, temporal b 
   JOIN avisosPrivacidad  ON temporal.correo = avisosPrivacidad.s1Correo 
   SET
   a.s1Correo                 = b.email,
   a.s1Giro                   = b.giro,
   a.s1DatosPersonales        = b.datosPersona,
   a.s1MotivoYUso             = b.usoInformacion,
   a.s4FinesDeTransferencia   = b.finesDeTransaccion,
   a.s7NombreSitioWeb         = b.nombreWeb,
   a.s8Actualizacion          = b.actualizacion
   WHERE a.s1Correo = b.email;"

Comment: @RicardoWallace you can drop the "a.s1Correo = b.email" line, because it is redundant.  Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: @WorkSmarter       Yeah i did get rid of that where, and still it does not update my first table and  no im not getting any errors

Comment: Is email or correo in your temporal table?

Comment: UPDATE avisosPrivacidad a, temporal b
SET
a.s1Giro = b.giro,
a.s1DatosPersonales = b.datosPersona,
a.s1MotivoYUso = b.usoInformacion,
a.s4FinesDeTransferencia = b.finesDeTransaccion,
a.s7NombreSitioWeb = b.nombreWeb,
a.s8Actualizacion = b.actualizacion
WHERE a.s1Correo = b.email;

Comment: @WorkSmarter so i tried your query and still the tables are the same thus there is no error log, i checked if it was my spelling, tripled checked the values and they are the same from my data base, emails in both tables are the same and everything

Comment: This SQL Fiddle demonstrates updating 1 table with another http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34975/1

Comment: @WorkSmarter thank you so much! now it works! it was also an error with my php file!